# NULL implementation and pointer assignment

Tags: c

I have a couple of questions that came up when I was reading and writing code..
I already get another approach, but this questions still in my mind and I didn't find any good answer, so let's see:

1. Can I assign a pointer to a variable in a portable way, even losing
   information? See the situation, I have a function that could return
   NULL if an error, or a char, supposing that NULL is all 0, the char
   will be nul, is this correct?

   ```
   void * function_returning_null_or_char ();
   ```
2. An int variable is suppose to hold a pointer? (I read it in somewhere)..
3. My implementation of NULL is `#define NULL (void *) 0`. Would be better if it was `#define NULL 0`? So
   it could be assigned to variable and pointers, like a char or an int
   *. (see question 1)
4. When I assign a pointer to NULL, when I cast it to short or char
   or another type, the value will be 0? Or The value will be the
   special value of NULL cutted to fit on that type?

I think that all questions are resumed in:
  The compiler is smart enough to convert a NULL pointer in 0s when it is cast to a variable?

example code:

```
    int *p = NULL;

    char c = (char) p; // This works, I dont know why, and char is equal to '/0';

    char c = NULL; //This works because the compiler is smart to convert NULL to '/0' event stddef.h defining NULL as (void *)0;

    char c = (char) function_returning_null_or_char (); //if this function return NULL whats the value of c? If NULL have a special value, c will have a special value too, or it will be 0?
```

Comment: Why are you redefining NULL?

Comment: you are just overcomplicating things...

Comment: I'm not redefining anything, That is in stddef.h

Comment: Then what are you trying to do??

Comment: wondering if is fine assign a pointer to a variable, if a pointer is NULL your value is suppose to be zero, so I think that is is fine..

Answer (score 3):

1. It doesn't make sense to have a function that can return either `NULL` (a pointer value) or a `char` value. There is a null *character* `'\0'`, but it's not related to the null pointer. There are various ways you can have a function return either a `char` value or some indication that there is no valid value. For example, return a structure.
2. No, an `int` variable is not supposed to hold a pointer. An `int` variable holds an integer value; to hold a pointer, use a pointer variable. (You can convert between integer and pointer types, but doing so makes sense far less often than you might think.)
3. `NULL` is defined for you by the implementation, in `<stddef.h>` and several other standard headers. Do not try to redefine it yourself.
4. Converting a null pointer value to an integer type yields an implementation-defined value. If you care what that value is, you're probably doing something wrong.

Pointers are not integers; don't try to treat them as integers. The representation of a null pointer is implementation-defined; it's commonly all-bits-zero, but there's no guarantee of that.

Take a look at the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly sections 4 (Pointers) and 5 (Null Pointers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already looked at comp.lang.c before asking, and thats bug me because, C++ implement NULL as 0, and C implement NULL as (void *)0. I was wondering that will be better C to implement NULL as 0 because it will useful both to pointer and nul char.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker; C != C++.

Comment: `NULL` should not be used to refer to a null character; it's a null *pointer* constant. C implementations can define `NULL` either as `((void*)0)` the outer parentheses are necessary) *or* as `0`, or in any of several other forms. C++, which is a different language, has different requirements for null pointer constants, and C++ implementations commonly define `NULL` as `0`. The point of having `NULL` define by the implementation is that you don't have to care how it's defined.

Comment: "Pointers are not integers; don't try to treat them as integers. The representation of a null pointer is implementation-defined; it's commonly all-bits-zero, but there's no guarantee of that." that's the answer I was looking for! many thanks keith thompson

Comment: I know that the problem to implement NULL as (void *) 0 is for variarg functions and another one I'm not remember now...

Comment: The point is, everything seems to work fine using NULL where NUL is expected, even people saying that is NULL was not made for that.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker: If you need to pass a null pointer to a variadic function in C that expects a `void*`, you should cast it to `void*`, because `NULL` may be defined so that its type is not a pointer type: `func(foo, bar, (void*)NULL)`. In other contexts, the compiler has enough information to *convert* a null pointer constant such as `NULL` to the appropriate pointer type.

Comment: sure? I thought it was old requeriment, I think that NULL was implemented as (void *)0 just for it.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker: There is no predefined identifier `NUL`; I think you mean `'\0'`, the null character. There are a lot of things you can (sometimes) get away with in C; for example, `int n = 1.0L;` will set `n` to `1`, but it's poor style. Just remember that `NULL` is intended *only* for use as a null pointer constant.

Comment: @drigoSkalWalker: Yes, I'm sure.